# Rellenar Select Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Buen día, estoy cargando datos en el select con ajax pero al abrirlo me dice **undefined** en las opciones, el código esta así:

```
    function get_driver(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '<?php echo base_url('admin/home/get_driver') ?>',
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(datos){
                $.each(datos,function(datos) {
                    $("#driver").append('<option value='+datos.id_driver+'>'+datos.nombre+'</option>');
                });    
            }
        }); 
        
    }
```

Y el select es este:

```
<select name="driver" id="driver" class="form-control form">
    <option value="">--Seleccione Driver--</option>
</select>
```

No sé cual es el problema

Comment: Faltan detalles... ¿has comprobado que la llamada AJAX obtiene una respuesta con los datos que esperas?

Comment: @PabloLozano De hecho si, eso he estado comprobado y si trae la respuesta JSON, al mostrarlo en el select no se muestra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veamos la función que se ejecuta cuando se obtiene una respuesta:

```
function(datos){
  $.each(datos,function(datos) {
    $("#driver").append('<option value='+datos.id_driver+'>'+datos.nombre+'</option>');
  });    
}
```

Por un lado tenemos algo que no es un fallo, pero que en general se suele evitar: estás ocultando una variable al declarar otra con el mismo nombre (`datos`).

Por otro lado, asumiendo que datos es un array, estás usando `$.each` en lugar de `datos.forEach`. Esto en sí tampoco es un fallo, pero es la causa de éste: mientras que una función se llama así:

```
datos.forEach(function (elemento, indice) {...});
```

la de jQuery se llama así:

```
$.each(datos, function (indice, elemento) {...});
```

Por tanto en tu código lo único que tienes es el índice del elemento, no el elemento en sí.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, logré encontrar lo que faltaba

Comment: Y ya funciona correctamente, gracias!